# ASP.Net Response.Redirect is ignored in button handler if refresh is pressed?

Tags: asp.net, event-handling, postback, response.redirect

Ok, I've got a particularly confusing problem, and I'm not sure what my best option is for fixing it.  I have an asp.net page with a button on it, and the handler for the button can (for reasons outside my immediate control/ability to fix) occasionally take a while to complete.  At the end of the handler, I've got a Response.Redirect call.  If the user hits Refresh while the button handler is running, it will finish running the handler for the button press (good) but then reload the page, instead of handling the Response.Redirect.

It took me FOREVER just to figure out that this is what was happening, but once I figured that out, I was able to reproduce it in some really super simple sample code.  I created a new C# .Net web project in VS 2010 (targeted to .Net 4), added a button to the home page:

```
<asp:button id="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" text="Submit"/>
```

and then added the handler code to just sleep for 10 seconds (to give me time to hit refresh):

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
    Response.Redirect("about.aspx");
}
```

And sure enough - if I let the button handler run, it redirects fine (obviously, as expected), but if I hit refresh during that 10 second Thread.Sleep, the response.Redirect gets ignored.

I need to figure out a way to force that Response.Redirect to get obeyed.  I have a feeling I have to just handle it in the Page_Load event that gets triggered by the user hitting Refresh (ie having a session variable that gets created, like a "handling_button" or something that I check for and just redirect if it's detected on page load, that gets removed when I get to the Redirect location), but I'm hoping there's something that I'm missing out here that's a bit more elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you hit <kbd>f5</kbd>, it instructs the browser to abandon the current page, and make a new request for the current address.

I don't think there is a clean solution for what you are trying to do.

javascript has the `window.onbeforeunload` property, but I don't think that will work here, because at the time the reload is requested, a navigation event has already been initiated.

It seems the only solution will be to have a test in your original page that will detect whether the request has been made yet or not.

It may help the users' perception to use a javascript event handler on the form submission to show a spinner too.

Comment: That's what I feared.  Oddly, I can't seem to find ANYBODY else ever having this problem, which leads me to believe that everybody else has just concluded what I did originally, and implemented the fix without bothering to check if anybody had a more elegant solution. :/ I'm definitely going to add a spinner, at the very least, though if my experience with users is any indication, a spinner won't prevent the majority of our users from just hitting refresh anyway.

Comment: Performing a long running calculation during server-side page generation is usually not the recommended approach which is probably why not very many people have encountered this.  The typical approach would be to put the job in a queue of some type or have some separate service process it so that the web server could return quickly.

Comment: Well, it's a checkout process for an online store (one that we acquired the source for, didn't create it ourselves), and it does quite a lot of stuff to submit an order.  We don't want to redirect the user to the receipt page until the order gets created, but an alternative solution may just be to send the user to an interstitial "order processing" page, to prevent the user from hitting refresh because they think it's timed out or otherwise frozen.